# How to update a non clientUpdateProhibited domain name?

Tags: dns, protocols

So I recently learned about [domain name locking](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/111390/36301) after having found the *.co domains of a top web site weren’t protected against server and client updating/transfering. *(while the .co tld offers all registrar locking protections)*

As the answer [of that question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/111390/36301) wasn’t descriptive on wheather this depict a real threat, I finally reported the issue to their security team *(plus an another bug that might enable to perform the theft from their own registrar website)*.

However, came up the killer’s question from their part :`how would it be possible to update contact details ?`
I don’t have even an idea of the involved protocols in such registrar transferring…

Comment: Historically?  Fax.  This is modern day, though, so I've no doubt people are doing it via tumblr or flickr or something else with no e.

Comment: @gowenfawr of course the aim is to answer the security team question's.

Comment: then the answer is "social engineering and alternate channels" (which is what I said, but with less flippancy).  Unfortunately, I can't make it descriptive, so it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: @gowenfawr ok but what i need is to understand the technial part, so I can understand what would differ from doing the same with a protection. Because social engineering targetting who: the current registrar staff?

Comment: For your homework, assess the weaknesses of this process: [Register.com Email Address Change Form](http://www.register.com/policy/forms/change_email_form.rcmx)

Comment: @gowenfawr : I don’t understand. Today many registrars performs things automatically. So for the current case, I can’t see the usecase of clientUpdateProhibited with Markmonitor, and in the meantime, MarkMonitor steal provide this as an option. There are even web‑based systems for automatic unlocked domain name transferring *(no human involved between registrars)*. I’m also really confused with this sentence I found`Completely locked domains cannot be modified using standard network protocols.`. Still thank you for keeping trying to explain things.